# Using fputcsv printing array instead of values when with Doctrine and Zend Framewrok

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine

Hi I'm using Doctrine as my ORM for my Zend App.

I was looking at exporting a query to a csv file however I get the following output

```
44  Brownie Don't feed after 8pm Array Array
```

So the pet name and their requirements are printing out (along with their ID for some reason) but the pet's breed and behavior are simply printing as ARRAY.

I realize that this is due to the query as the behavior and breed information are stored within their own array within the result array but how can I get these values to export to the file.
I've tried adding where clauses to the query to match the pets breed and behavior to the primary keys of the related table but it did not work so I removed them.

The code for my action is below

```
 public function todayscatterybookingstofileAction()
  {
    $today=date('y-m-d');
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
         ->select('p.name,b.breed,h.behaviour,p.special_requirements')
         ->from('PetManager_Model_Pets p')
         ->leftJoin('p.PetManager_Model_Breeds b')
         ->leftJoin('p.PetManager_Model_Behaviour h')
         ->leftJoin('p.PetManager_Model_Catterypets s')
         ->leftJoin('s.PetManager_Model_Catterybooking k')
         ->where('s.bookingID = k.catterybookingID')
         ->andWhere('p.petID=s.pet')
         ->andwhere('k.srtDate < ?',$today) 
         ->andWhere('k.edDate >= ?',$today)
         ->andWhere('k.catteryappointmentstatus=1');
           $result = $q->fetchArray();


 $description="D:/reports/Occupied Catteries";

 $extension=".csv";

 $filename=$description.$today.$extension;

 $file = fopen($filename,"w");      


  foreach($result as $line)
   {

      fputcsv($file,$line);

   }

    fclose($file);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Doctrine 1.1 or higher, you may be able to use the HYDRATE_SCALAR option to force a flat array:

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
         ->select('p.name,b.breed,h.behaviour,p.special_requirements')
         ->from('PetManager_Model_Pets p')
         ->leftJoin('p.PetManager_Model_Breeds b')
         ->leftJoin('p.PetManager_Model_Behaviour h')
         ->leftJoin('p.PetManager_Model_Catterypets s')
         ->leftJoin('s.PetManager_Model_Catterybooking k')
         ->where('s.bookingID = k.catterybookingID')
         ->andWhere('p.petID=s.pet')
         ->andwhere('k.srtDate < ?',$today) 
         ->andWhere('k.edDate >= ?',$today)
         ->andWhere('k.catteryappointmentstatus=1')->setHydrationMode(Doctrine::HYDRATE_SCALAR);
```

and that should give you a flat list.

Comment: I'm using Doctrine 1.2.3 but adding this method as you have shown has not worked.

Comment: Interesting: could have sworn that should do the right thing. Try doing `$result = $q->fetchArray(array(), Doctrine::HYDRATE_SCALAR);` and see if that helps?

Comment: No still gives me the same result weird, I can't get on the the Doctrine site at the moment as my connection is crap and keeps it timing out.

Comment: Its not your connection: the Doctrine website is crap right now. Could have sworn that should have worked, though :). You may need to `array_map` with a function that plucks out the first element if the item at that position is an array. Its inefficient but it will get you there in short order.

Comment: thanks for your help, I'm going to leave this for a while until I can get back onto the site. I've got other query problems to deal with :-)